# Is it wrong to use "sliding"?

Tags: word-choice

I have heard people refer to kids *sliding* and kids *sledding*. Is it wrong to say "we are going sliding"?

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with either "sliding" or "sledding", in the US, as a term for the activity of sliding on snow or ice.  The terms do tend to be regional, however.  (I understand those snooty Brits insist on calling it "sledging", though.)

Comment: @HotLicks BrE tends to associate *sled* with dogs and pack-ice, and *sledge* with children and snowy hillsides.

Comment: If you’re sufficiently posh and averse to actually propelling the thing yourself, you may even find yourself _sleighing_.

Comment: The caribou in the room here that nobody seems to notice is *tobogganing*.

Comment: "Sliding" is what we used to do on our feet, as children - along a stretch of frozen playground or pavement. The more you slid the more slippery it became.

Comment: @tchrist Yes. Tobogganing is far posher than sledging.

Answer (score 2):

When I was growing up sliding was what happened when someone was pushed down a hill without the apparatus to ride on. Sledding was going down the hill with your toboggan or otherwise instrument of potential snow hill destruction.

I do not think either way is inaccurate as there are always regional differences in the way individuals refer to items and actions.

Comment: I was just going to say the same thing. Sliding was sledding without a sledge.

Comment: [This Quebec City article](http://www.quebecregion.com/en/what-to-do/activities-attractions/ideas/sliding/) seems to use 'sliding' as a hypernym for sledging etc.

Comment: If you search ["go sliding" snow] you can easily see more examples like that Edwin cites above.

Comment: When I was a kid, "sledding" was something you did with a sled.  "Sliding" was with a toboggan (when it wasn't "tobogganing").  But that was in Kentucky where any such activity was rare.  Here in Minnesota I hear "sliding" probably more often than "sledding", for any of the activities.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that "sledding" with an honest-to-goodness Flexible Flyer sled is only possible when the snow is less than about 5" deep (which was usually the case in Kentucky).  Whereas snow in Minnesota most winters (this one being an exception) is generally of an 8-12 inch depth for most of the winter.  So one can't often use a true "sled", and hence "sliding" makes more sense.

Comment: @HotLicks One can go tobogganing in any snow depth. Kids now use plastic toboggans all the time. Plus there are those little saucers.

Comment: @tchrist - Yes, it's changed a bit with the plastic things (whatever you call them).  And, of course, snowmobilers have in the past few years co-opted "sledding" for their use.  All this contributes even more to the regional variations.

Answer (score 1):

Sledding requires a sled (or as some responders have called it, a sledge. I think "sledge" is British; I know Americans call it a sled.)

I went sledding as a kid, in western Washington state. What matters is not how deep the snow is, but how wet it is, and whether it is compacted or re-frozen so as to have a relatively hard surface. Such compacted snow occurs often in wetter zones, whereas parts that are dry in winter (Colorado, Minnesota, etc) are more likely to have "fluffy" snow, which is too soft for sledding, because the narrowness of the sled's runners concentrates the rider's weight on a few square inches. Driven-on roads (after a few inches of snow) which then get some sun to barely melt the surface, make ideal sled runs. You could even "slide" on your shoes, standing up, on such icy snow.

But you can "slide" on any kind of snow with anything you can sit on (a plastic disk, a piece of cardboard, etc) which distibutes your weight so as to not dig into the snow—provided the hill is steep enough.

Answer (score 0):

It is sledding. Same as biking. Biking is not rolling you may say I'm rolling down the street on my bike but it isn't called rolling. Also just like you use a sled you use skates and skating is not sliding you may be sliding on the ice but it is skating.

Comment: But "biking" is riding a motorcycle.  Riding a bicycle is called "cycling".

Comment: @HotLicks Not universally. Biking can refer to riding a bicycle. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bike.